# Save current shell history and recover it afterwards

Tags: bash, shell

Sometimes I work very intensively using a certain set of commands in the bash shell and then I spend some days working in a very different one. The problem is that by the time I want to keep going with the first set of tasks the shell history has been totally overwritten by the last one and I spend some time figuring out what I was exactly doing (I lack long-term memory).

I usually keep a journal so I can go back and continue where I stopped the last time, but I was wondering if there exists an easy way to do some "time travelling" in my shell session by saving the recent shell history (say, the last 100 commands) to a file and using this file to overwrite the history in the future.

Comment: You can get the history by calling `history` command in the shell and just save the output to the file `history > my_history.txt`

Comment: History is usually stored in `~/.bash_history` for bash and `~/.zsh_history` for zsh unless specified.

Comment: Yeah, but can I use that `my_history.txt` file to overwrite the current history in the future?

Comment: You need to execute all the commands in my_history.txt (bash my_history.txt) again to get it as current history.

Comment: Well I just found out you  can call `history -r my_history.txt` to read the history from a file. For some reason I did not found it on the manpage. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Why don't you put this commands into a shell script?

Comment: @cnluzon You need to check `help history` instead of `man history` since it is a builtin command.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks, I was trying --help and man history instead. I got a manpage but didn't find anything about reading it from a file. I do not put the commands into a shell script because I don't want to execute them all, I just want to have them recovered to the history so I can get back in track of what I was doing faster.

Comment: Ok, then `history -r` looks like the right command. Why not answering your own question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the `history` command actually has options for reading/writing files. You can write a history file with `history -w my_history.txt` and then import a history file by typing `history -r my_history.txt`.

**Note**: Be careful with simply writing the result of `history` command to a file with `history > my_history.txt` and then importing it, because that will write to history also the command numbers.